# viewbag data is empty in $.ajax

Tags: viewbag

Iam using asp.net mvc4 and facing some problem in accessing viewbag.price.

This is what i am doing:-

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FillModel(int id)
    {
        var vehModel = db.Vehicle_Model.Where(vehMod => vehMod.MakeID == id).ToList().Select(vehMod => new SelectListItem() { Text = vehMod.Model, Value = vehMod.pkfModelID.ToString() });

        ViewBag.Price = 100;
        return Json(vehModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

i am calling above using below:-

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("FillModel","Waranty")',
            type: 'post',
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ddModel').empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                    var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                    $(optionTag).val(val.Value).text(val.Text);
                    $('#ddModel').append(optionTag);
                });

                var a = '@ViewBag.Price';
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

But i am not able to access ViewBag.Price.

Anyone know the reason??

thanks

Comment: hmmmmm didn't get any response of my question.....although i got my solution simply by returning additional parameter instead of setting viewbag but still wonder why not able to get viewbag value in my view.....

Comment: var a = @ViewBag.Price;
Remove colons around viewbag.price.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't able to access items from the ViewBag inside your ajax success function is because the view that contains your script has already been rendered by the Razor view engine, effectively setting the variable `a` to whatever the value of `@ViewBag.Price` was at the time the page was rendered.

Looking at the process flow might be helpful:

(1) The request comes in for the view that has your script fragment in it.

(2) The controller method that returns your view is called.

(3) The Razor view engine goes through the view and replaces any references to `@ViewBag.Price` in your view with the actual value of `ViewBag.Price`. Assuming `ViewBag.Price` doesn't have a value yet, the success function in your script is now

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#ddModel').empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, val) {
        var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
        $(optionTag).val(val.Value).text(val.Text);
        $('#ddModel').append(optionTag);
    });

    var a = '';
}
```

(4) The rendered html gets sent to the client

(5) Your ajax request gets triggered

(6) On success, `a` gets set to the empty string.

As you had mentioned in the comments of your question, the solution to this problem is to include `a` in the Json object returned by your action method, and access it using `data.a` in your script. The return line would look like

```
return Json(new { 
    model =  vehModel,
    a = Price
});
```

Keep in mind that if you do this, you'll have to access model data in your ajax success function with `data.model.Field`. Also, you shouldn't need to specify the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` option, since your method only responds to posts and your ajax request is a post.